# Add item to inittab on OpenSuse 12.1

Tags: opensuse, startup, init

I am currently working on a project which needs to be added to `inittab` so that the program loads during startup.

The program that I am trying to start is a c# mono application. I have created a start script and if the start script is run manually the program launches fine. However, when I put it into `inittab` the program doesn't launch.

I've checked in `/var/log/messages` but it doesn't say anything is wrong, it just says that it is reloading.

Below is what I have added to my `inittab` script

```
bes:2345:respawn:/home/bits/MyProgram/start.myprogram
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

**UPDATE**
Below is the code in the start script which is located in /home/bits/MyProgram.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/bits/MyProgram

/usr/bin/mono EmailServer.exe "$@"
```

I have also tried adding > mylog.txt onto the end of the line beginning with /usr/bin/mono e.g.

> /usr/bin/mono EmailServer.exe "$@" > mylog.txt

If I run the start script manually, even if I am not in the directory where the start script is located it works fine, its just when I add it to inittab and run telinit q it never starts and the log isn't written to but the log does get written to if I start the program manually.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Bad enough that you use mono on a linux system. But placing it into inittab is horrible. Go for a proper /etc/init.d/ script.

Comment: What distribution are you using and what do you mean with inittab script?

Comment: @UlrichDangel I'm using OpenSuse 12.1 and by inittab I mean /etc/inittab which is where you can add things to load up on startup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simple, you are using OpenSuse 12.1 which [uses](http://news.opensuse.org/2011/12/22/systemd-%E2%80%93-boot-faster-and-cleaner-with-opensuse-12-1/) [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) instead of your classic [System V boot system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SysV).

To install a new service place create following file in /etc/systemd/system/myprogname.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My progname service file

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/bits/MyProgram

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Aftwards run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl start myprogname.service`

If you want to automatically restart MyProgname you have to add

```
Restart=restart-always
```

to the service section.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this has been driving me crazy, this is very will hidden compared to using inittab

Answer (score 6):

Put your program somewhere.

Copy and edit the skeleton template file for init job control found at **/etc/init.d/skeleton**.

Modify this file to indicate WHICH runlevel you want... in your example, you want 2,3,4,5, there are options at top of file (in comments) to indicate desired runlevels

Place this new file in **/etc/init.d** with a descriptive name. (*myfancyname* used in example)

A platform agnostic method to test this, or to enable/disable (if you used the *skeleton* file)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/myfancyname start
sudo /etc/init.d/myfancyname stop
sudo /etc/init.d/myfancyname restart
```

There are distribution specific methods to perform these same actions, for instance, Debian uses *update-rc.d myfancyname [start|stop|enable|disable...]*

Modifying inittab is *generally* a **bad** idea, if you screw it up, the system no longer boots, and then you've got TWO problems. (no regex needed!)

Adding scripts to the /etc/init.d/ subdirectory is more standardized, can be used with almost ANY linux flavor, probably some *nix's, maybe some bsd's.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `telinit q` to tell init to reload `/etc/inittab`, it won't do that automatically. I think you've done that since you mention the `Re-reading inittab` message (you did see this message, right?) in the system logs.

Is the problem that your process isn't starting at all, or that your program fails during its startup? Write a wrapper script that redirects errors to a log file:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec >/var/log/myprogram.log 2>&1 
exec /home/bits/MyProgram/start.myprogram
```

Check if the log file is created and see if any errors appear in it.

One thing that comes to mind is that your program may require environment variables that are set in your session. The `init` process has a very limited environment. If necessary, modify the wrapper script to set all needed variables.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to get back to you, my test virtual machine stopped working took me a while to work out what was wrong. Anyway, I've tried what you suggested but that doesn't start either, its not my program failing to start, its just not ever starting the program. I've added the content of my start script to my question in case it helps.

Comment: @Boardy Did you try with an absolute path for the log file? Do you see the `Re-reading inittab` message?

Comment: Yep, I tried that and it is saying that it is reloading after I run telinit q

Answer (score 1):

When `init` reads a *Command* to execute in `inittab`, it forks a shell and sends the *Command* as a parameter to the `exec` command in that shell. So, check what happens if you manually do:

```
sh -c exec /home/bits/MyProgram/start.myprogram
```

Another thing that I would try, would be to bypass the launcher script altogether, with something like this in inittab:

```
bes:2345:respawn:/usr/bin/mono /home/bits/MyProgram/EmailServer.exe "$@"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, neither of those worked, both attempts the program doesn't run

Comment: If the program doesn't run with the first command, it won't run from `inittab`, so you need to temporarily ignore `inittab` and troubleshoot why the script doesn't launch generally. Is `/home/bits/MyProgram/start.myprogram` executable?

Comment: Yep, if I can run it from any location on the server not necessarily where the file is stored and the program launches successfully.

Comment: @MariosZindillis Just found out if I run the executable, instead of the start script using ``exec /home/bits/MyProgram/EmailServer.exe`` it comes up with an error stating ``-bash: /home/bits/EmailServer/EmailServer.exe: Permission denied
-bash: exec: /home/bits/EmailServer/EmailServer.exe: cannot execute: Permission denied``

Comment: @MariosZindillis I've just tried running a basic script that doesn't attempt to execute my program, it will instead just write a word to a file and this file never gets written but if I run the script manually it does.