# Why process will not start in Inittab

Tags: opensuse, init

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Add item to inittab on OpenSuse 12.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42671/add-item-to-inittab-on-opensuse-12-1)

I have the following entry in my /etc/inittab (on OpenSuse 12.1):

```
gp:2345:respawn:/usr/local/gpm/bin/gpsrvd
```

Which won't execute no matter what I try to do.

- comment it out
- run `init q`
- uncomment it
- run `init q` again

Still it will not run!

I then run it manually as root:

```
lorraine:/home/joseph # /usr/local/gpm/bin/gpsrvd &
[1] 5646
```

and it runs :

```
lorraine:/home/joseph # ps aux | grep gpsr
root      5646  0.0  0.0  45960  2276 pts/0    S    12:24   0:00 /usr/local/gpm/bin/gpsrvd
```

So, what could be different when running this via init? Does the init behavior vary in 12.1 that it was on earlier versions of OpenSuse?

Thanks in advance for constructive answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSuse 12.1 has switched to [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) which doesn't use `/etc/inittab` anymore but `/etc/systemd/` with separate configuration files instead.

Comment: thanks I've tried checking the docs for how I might do this in the new `systemd` world, but can't seem to make any progress. All I can see is docs dealing with services, sockets, daemons, etc. But what about emulating / replacing `inittab` usecases like this one?

Comment: @nemesisfixx see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43176/8979 for details, it is basically the exact same question