# Application does not start from inittab

Tags: sysvinit

I am trying to launch an application via inittab in an embedded system. The desire to do this via inittab rather than through an init.d script is to avail of respawn. There is no systemd on this system. I have the following entry in inittab: `myapp::respawn:/path/to/my/app`.
Try what I may, it does not start. Per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43053/) answer I have observed the following (launching manually):

```
sh -c /path/to/my/app         # works
sh -c exec /path/to/my/app    # does not work
sh -c 'exec /path/to/my/app'  # works
```

Per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42694/) answer the following shell script also works:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /path/to/my/app
```

Currently I start the application via an init.d script thus: `su - root -c '/path/to/my/app &'` and it works but this same command does not work either in inittab. My fallback would be to have yet another monitor script launched from init.d that keeps running and re-launches my application if it is not found in `ps` output, but it would be much nicer to get the "automatic" respawn facility via inittab.

Answer (score 0):

Right after I posted, vaguely remembered noting in the past that inittab labels need to be below a certain length (this is a buildroot-generated system). And indeed, changing the inittab entry to `app::respawn:/path/to/my/app` works! Looks like labels need to be 4 characters or less. Leaving this question up in case it helps someone.